# Visual Studio inserting indents as spaces to html output

Tags: asp.net, html, visual-studio, line-endings

I am using Visual Studio 2010 for an MVC website project. I have an big problem and dont know hot to solve it. When i am looking to the output of html in firebug indents in my aspx and ascx files are outputed as space in same places. I think its about line ending of files but i am not sure how to fix them. I am adding some pictures about problem.[image]

[image]

[image]

When i am adding a breakpoint it also add red background to spaces (this is problem) I try to delete spaces after hit ctrl+k d same problem happen.
If i delete all indents make page 1 line without spaces output is fine but it not a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASPX/ASCX engine emits literal content within markup as is i.e if your file has spaces or tabs for indentation then they will be output as is. You can use Tools->Options for keeping tabs (instead of space) for indents - you can change for all languages or say only for HTML. VS 2010 has a great extension [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef) that will (apart from other things) warn you if your file has tabs & space mix and allows you to choose either tabs or spaces.

Now as a better solution, you can use HttpModule to remove whitespace from your response - see http://madskristensen.net/post/A-whitespace-removal-HTTP-module-for-ASPNET-20.aspx

Comment: thanks for your answer, i dont want to use a third party tool, because this problem isnt occured before. also i dont want to change tools>options keeping tabs because there isnt one developer, project is under source control of TFS, all developers need to change this. Also indets that translate as space to output isnt occured in all lines for example in the first picture line that has breakpoint has problem, other lines dont have this problem :(